# Is Acrobat reader X coming to Ubuntu?

Tags: adobe-acrobat

Do we know when Adobe release X reader for Ubuntu? It has some good features!

Comment: I've found this -- http://forums.adobe.com/thread/753068?tstart=0 -- topic at dobe forum, but there's no answer...

Comment: What features does it have that, say, Evince does not?

Comment: Highlighting and Comments?

Comment: hey adobe....bring your new version for ubuntu as well. Otherwise we will create better than adobe reader x. :P

Comment: Adobe Reader X definitely needs to be ported to Ubuntu.

Comment: @Michael I'm guessing that Evince doesn't have built-in, extremely fast OCR?

Comment: Sometime in the future some of us will encounter important forms requiring features not supported by Adobe Reader 9.4.6. Without Adobe Reader X for Linux, where will we be then?

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is MAYBE. The long answer is, as flash support, Adobe might take a long while to bring this to linux. Big chance that they will bring it as a proprietary software.

Anyway for alternatives you can use the following:

ePDFView
Evince
KPDF
okular
Xpdf

Extracted just my coincidence from a webpage i was working on back in 2008:

http://neogm.com/compatibilidad/

Which i seriously need to update to mysql and php XD.

Answer (score 4):

try running pdf Xchange reader with Wine. It features a very customizable UI, tab support, highlighting and comments.

Comment: It has OCR too.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a very nice and fast alternative to Acrobat Reader - FoxitReader for Linux [FoxitSoftware PDF Reader web site](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/desklinux/). I am very glad that Foxit released a reader for Linux platform (I am using this software on Windows PCs and I am very satisfied of the performance).

Comment: I understand that it was not an answer on the question above. But I suppose that people should know of a variety of options :)

Comment: unfortunately only 32bit binaries are available

Comment: While alternatives are useful, I would suggest that you only answer what is asked in cases like this.

Comment: Roland, you  are right. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: What's wrong with Evince (the PDF reader that is included with Ubuntu)?

Comment: AFAIK Evince doesn't support new technologies Adobe Inc provides

Comment: Foxit 1.1 is Cool ! ..... thank you for the suggestion. Voted up !

Answer (score 3):

If you like to highlight, underline and make comments in pdf files, then there are no **real** alternatives to the windows version of Adobe reader or the windows version of Foxit Reader. Best is to use Foxit Reader under wine (the linux version of Foxit reader is only a reader without these functions). Also, the Evince developers do not have time to implement these features into Evince.

Comment: Thats why I need Adobe acrobat 10 in ubuntu, I'm not addicted to Adobe aplications. I need something for different platforms, can read from different people and Adobe is the most known app for .pdf  files.

Answer (score 1):

Try djvu, it has several readers, it's very fast, there are several readers that are better to use than evince or foxitreader , and there's a pdf->djvu converter in the linux repositories (Idk what it's called in ubuntu but in my distribution the package is called pdf2djvu, just do sudo apt-cache search djvu).

From the looks of it, acrobat reader X might end up like the linux version of flash; a buggy port after 5 years of waiting.

Answer (score 1):

Guess what, I also needed to install Adobe X, but in my case, in order to use the multimedia pdf files created by the LiveScribe software.

Fortunately, I downloaded Adobe Reader X for Windows XP SP2, gave the install file  autorization to execute and installed it using wine (I have Ubuntu 10.04).

One thing I had to do was to tell it to use the "unproteceted" mode ????

All is ok. It opens, and plays the audio along with the pen notes I took.